# React-Native run while app is killed

Tags: geolocation, react-native, background-task

I have this use case:

- Send geo location to the server every 3 minutes even if the android app has been killed.

I have tried several different libraries (react-native-background-task, react-native-background-timer, Headless js) but none of them work if you close the app. Does someone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this library

```
react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation
```

It works with app closed both in android and ios